# RexCall cannot be cast to RexInputRef exception in Apache Beam SQL

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, beam-sql

I'm trying to do a simple join using Beam SQL but I'm getting an exception while compilation:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_sdks_java_extensions_sql.org.apache.calcite.rex.RexCall cannot be cast to org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_sdks_java_extensions_sql.org.apache.calcite.rex.RexInputRef
```

The join is something like:

```
select T1.x from table1 T1 join table2 T2
on 
(case when T1.a = 'ABC' then 'ABC' else T1.b end = T2.c)
```

This condition works fine when executed in BigQuery (tried as a sanity check). Not sure why it's breaking in Beam SQL. I even tried using Beam SQL UDF but it did not help either. I assume it's because of Apache Calcite and the format it follows but I do not know how to handle it.

Can someone please help with this.

Comment: I don't believe something like this is supported in Beam SQL at the moment. Only field equality joins are expected to work. `CASE` should work in `SELECT` though, so you might be able to model this as `JOIN` between a table and a select, similar to this: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/testing/nexmark/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/nexmark/queries/sql/SqlQuery7.java#L60

Comment: There is a JIRA related to this exception: https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6112. Contribution will definitely very welcomed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Can you try the `IF` conditioning? I hope this will work:

```
select T1.x from table T1 join table T2 on IF(T1.a = 'ABC', 'ABC',T1.b) = T2.c
```